# Storing only certain $_GET request values

Tags: php, foreach, get

Currently I have this code that stores all $_GET requests:

```
  $array_name = array();
  foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
      $array_name[] = "'%".escape_string($value)."%'";
  }
```

My goal is to somehow only store certain values, if for example I have 5 different $_GET request, named 1,2,3,4 and 5. I only want to store 1-3 in this array. How would this be possible?

Comment: You could use [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to check if the `$key` is in your predefined array of allowed keys (e.g. `$keys = [1, 2, 3];`). Wrapping your `$array_name ...` line in an if checking this condition, you would skip all other keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array_name = array();
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  if(in_array($key, array(1, 2, 3)))
    $array_name[] = "'%".escape_string($value)."%'";
  }
}
```

It this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the intersection of an array of keys you want:

```
foreach(array_intersect_key($_GET, array_flip([1,2,3])) as $value) {
      $array_name[] = "'%".escape_string($value)."%'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach to the other answers. `$keysToStore` is an array of the keys you want to store.

The foreach loop then pulls these values from the `$_GET` array rather than looping the entire array.

```
$keysToStore = [1, 2, 3];

$array_name = [];
foreach ( $keysToStore as $key ) {
    $array_name[] = "'%" . escape_string( $_GET[$key] ) . "%'";
}
```

Edit: can check `isset` inside the loop if keys are not validated elsewhere.

```
$keysToStore = [1, 2, 3];

$array_name = [];
foreach ( $keysToStore as $key ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET[$key] ) ) {
        $array_name[] = "'%" . escape_string( $_GET[$key] ) . "%'";
    }
}
```

Comment: But this will throw and exception if, for example, `$_GET[2]` is not set.

Comment: @Johannes True. But op has only provided a small snippet of code, it is not known where the keys come from or how they are validated. It's easy enough to check isset inside the loop. See my update.

Answer (score -1):

For this, you need to add check on $key, that $key has value 1 or 2 or 3. Sample code is this:

```
 $array_name = array();
 foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if($key == '1' || $key == '2' || $key == '3'){
      $array_name[] = "'%".escape_string($value)."%'";
    }
 }
```

Or the other sample code is:

```
 $array_name = array();
 foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
     if(in_array($key, array(1, 2, 3))){
      $array_name[] = "'%".escape_string($value)."%'";
    }
 }
```

Here 1 , 2 and 3 is key of $_GET. Sample input is: $_GET['1'] = 'Ghazal' , $_GET['2'] = 'Taimur' ,  $_GET['3'] = 'Malik' , $_GET['4'] = 'Test' ,  $_GET['5'] = 'City'

Comment: This solution seems right but is not scalable because you will get endless "or" chain.

Comment: @Johannes Use   if(in_array($key, array(1, 2, 3))) condition for this

Comment: Sure, but I think your answer is "too limited" to the example in the question.